# Extracting Lat/Lng from Shapefile using OGR2OGR/GDAL

Tags: shapefile, gdal

I'm trying to extract lattitude/longitude values for the streets in this shapefile:
http://gispub02.sfgov.org/website/sfshare/catalog/stclines_streets.html

I've seen it reommended in many places that I use this command to do so:

*(Below does work! Spelling error fixed.)*

> ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv STCLINES_STREETS.shp -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ

However, when I do so, I get a CSV containing a lot of useful information about the streets -- names, neighborhoods, etc -- but no actual lat/long values.

What am I doing wrong? I'm a GDAL noob so am sure I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I am able to extract coordinates if I output to GML instead of CSV. This isn't ideal, and it isn't what's described in the GDAL documentation, but it will suffice for me for now...

Comment: You have done some conversion? Because your coordinate with the original SHP are not in lat, long but x, y coordinates in NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_III_FIPS_0403_Feet
meters (epsg code 2227). Use ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 STCLINES_STREETS_WGS84.shp STCLINES_STREETS.shp to get true lat, long

Answer (score 6):

It's very likely that AS_XYZ only works for point layers.  If you are trying to extract a single XYZ for lines, what XYZ would that be?  The start point? mid point? end point?

Trying GEOMETRY=AS_WKT instead will give you the component points of the line.
See http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_csv.html

Comment: That makes sense. I think I was hoping for a startpoint and endpoint, though in retrospect I suppose it's likely that many streets aren't simple straight lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, AS_WKT is producing a CSV identical to AS_XYZ. Neither flag is successfully extracting GPS coords.

Comment: make sure you spell GEOMETRY correctly! (you have GEMOETRY in your original post... does that fix it?)

Comment: ah. yes that fixed it. *facepalm*